# generate all binary trees with n nodes OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a code that generates all binary trees with `n` nodes (so the program has to return a list in which we can find all the different binary trees with `n` nodes).

Here is the way I represent binary trees :

```
type 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

So I am trying to implement a function `all_tree : int -> tree list` such that :

1. `all_tree 0 = [Empty]`
2. `all_tree 1 = [Node('x',Empty,Empty)]`
3. `all_tree 2 = [Node('x',Node('x',Empty,Empty),Empty); Node('x',Empty,Node('x',Empty,Empty))]`
4. ...

I tried several ideas but it didn't work out. For example we could try the following :

```
let rec all_tree result = function
   |0 -> r
   |s -> all_tree ((List.map (fun i -> Node('x',i,Empty)) result)@(List.map (fun i -> Node('x',Empty,i)) result) ) (s-1)
in all_tree [Empty] (*some number*)
```

This code doesn't work because it doesn't generate every possibility.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't generate every possibility?

Comment: Because for example I never get the binary tree Node('x',Node('x',Empty,Empty),Node('x',Empty,Empty))

Comment: How did you arrive at that being a possibility, and why do you think your code does not find it. Please be specific. "Doesn't work" isn't a very useful problem description.

Comment: It would also help if you formatted your code properly and named variables in a meaningful way. What does `r` and `i` mean? And providing a printing function would make it easier to inspect the output and see what the problem might be.

Comment: You might want to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and try to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that my question is not clear because I am not asking to correct my code because it's false. I just want ideas to solve the problem or a complete solution. Also r stand as result (and Idescribed it in the definition of my function all_tree) and I am explicity using List.map so why should I described i ??

Comment: _I just want ideas to solve the problem or a complete solution._ That is not really what SO is for, as the link I posted above explains. You should format your code and name your variables properly even if you explain it elsewhere, because it requires less effort to understand your code if you do. And if you won't bother to make the effort to help us help you, why should we bother to try to help you?

Comment: I am sure everything is clear but I'll change the variable r to result as it seems to really matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible answer.

```ml
let rec all_trees = function
  | 0 -> [Empty]
  | n ->
  let result = ref [] in
  for i = 0 to n-1 do
    let left_side = all_trees i
    and right_side = all_trees (n-1-i) in
    List.iter
      (fun left_tree ->
        List.iter
          (fun right_tree ->
            result := (Node('x', left_tree, right_tree)) :: (!result)
          )
          right_side
      )
      left_side
  done;
  !result
;;
```

It's pretty simple: a tree with n>0 nodes is a tree with 1 node at the top, and then n-1 nodes below split between a certain number on the left and a certain number on the right. So we loop for i from 0 to n-1 through all possible numbers of values on the left side, and n-i-1 is going to be the number of nodes on the right side. We recursively call `all_trees` to get the trees with i and n-i-1 nodes, and simply aggregate them.

Notice that it's a *very poor* implementation. It has everything a recursive function should avoid. See something like [this page on recursive implementations of the Fibonacci sequence](http://cubbi.com/fibonacci/ocaml.html) to see how to improve it (one of the first things to do would be to cache the results rather than recompute the same things many many times).

---

I do agree with the question's comments though that writing a printer would be step 1 in that kind of project, because it's really annoying having to read through messy things like `[Node ('x', Node ('x', Empty, Node ('x', Node ('x', Empty, Empty), Empty)), Empty);`. Naming variables better would also make it easier for people to read your code and will increase the chance someone will help you. And generally, listening to the comments when people give you advice on how to properly ask your questions will make it easier for you to get answers both right now and in your future questions. For instance, in my own code, I used `i` as the loop index. It makes sense to me while I'm coding it, but when you read the code, maybe you would have preferred to read something like `left_side_nodes` or something like that, which would have made it obvious what this variable was supposed to do. It's the same in your own scenario: you could call `i` something like `subtree` or maybe something even more explicit. Actually, properly naming it could make you realize what's wrong with your code. Often, if you can't properly name a variable, it's that you don't really understand what it's doing (even local variables).